# Update v-model variable in another function

Tags: vuejs3

This maybe a very simple problem, but I didn't find any useful information after searching for some hours. Consider the following code:

```
<script setup>
var code = 123;

function run() {
    code = 5456;
}
</script>

<template>
    <input v-model="code" /> <button @click="run">Run</button>
</template>
```

When I click button, the value shown in input is not changed.

I tried `ref` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref works - try this code:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

var code = ref(123);

function run() {
    code.value = 5456;
}
</script>

<template>
    <input v-model="code" /> <button @click="run">Run</button>
</template>
```

You can confirm it here on [Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNo9jbsOgzAMRX/FygIMBfVBhzag9hc6Z6FpkKKCEwUnC+Lf6wip3q7v46zi6X2dohE3IRcdrCdYDEXfK7Szd4FghWBG2GAMboaCo4VChWkIoN3HQJft8ng6V/f8HyNqsg4hRCwrWBUCX07WaZhizreX9srZTaFsdiTDWJCZ/TSQYZU70qKPBOkwc3nqlMgjSkDTg3xHImY89GT1ly2GKdG/Ii/uFm/I5j8oth/p+E7o)

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I didn't know that we have to use `code.value` when setting value.

Comment: You can read about it in depth here in the [vue docs - reactivity-core](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html)